# Problems with spool [ORACLE]

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle12c

I have this running in SQLplus

```
spool TypeDrop.sql
select distinct 'drop type '||object_name|| ';' from user_objects where object_type='TYPE';
spool off
```

It prints out to TypeDrop.sql:

```
SQL> select distinct 'drop type '||object_name||';' from user_objects where object_type='TYPE';
drop type ADDRESS_OBJTYP; 
drop type PERSON_OBJTYP;                                                                                                                                              
SQL> spool off
```

When I execute the following statement:

```
sqlplus -s system/passwd @TypeDrop.sql
```

Oracle returns me errors because the query starts with "SQL>". Does anyone know how to remove "SQL>" from the file TypeDrop.sql. Thanks you.

---

TypeDrop.sql

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these line at the top of your script:

```
SET HEADING OFF
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET FEEDBACK OFF

spool TypeDrop.sql
select distinct 'drop type '||object_name|| ';' from user_objects where object_type='TYPE';
spool off
exit
```

Depending on your query you may have to add also these ones:

```
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
```

Comment: I have done your queried and the following information appears in the file "TypeDrop.sql". PS: I edit the post.

Comment: You have to exit the script.

Comment: sorry, I do not understand you. How to exit the script?

Comment: Maybe when you enter EXOT